# Spring Boot, Feign static header from configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-feign

I'm having some issues fetching the API-key from the application.yml file for my FeignClient.

```
@FeignClient(name="CRM-api", url="${api_url}", configuration= <myConfiguration.class>)
@Headers({"Authorization: ${api_key}"})
public interface CRMAPIClient {
```

Is it even possible to have a placeholder value in the Headers annotation? I've tired setting the headers on each endpoint too, but it still can't retrieve the configuration for the api-key. I manage to get the ${api_url} but not the ${api_key} value

// Linus

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use this approach, but I will take a look into this.
But if the requirement is to inject the Authorization header to you client request then better way to write  in BasicAuthRequestIntercepter ( for reference look how feign used) then in that add the header to every request for your client.
If you are using annotations to define your feign client then use configuration property to define configuration class and then in that class override intercepter related method and return your own intercepter.
Sample code:

```
import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("Authorization", ${API_KEY});
     }
 }
```

Then inject this class to your feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name="service",configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
```

Points to be noted:(taken from other post)
Using @Configuration here causes this bean to be applied to all @FeignClient and you do not need the configuration = part. If you remove @Configuration then this bean is ignored, and the configuration = part does nothing.
The correct way to do this (if you want it just on one specific @FeignClient) is to add @Configuration and then exclude it from @ComponentScan with excludeFilters

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the "$" sign in @Headers

Yes, you can send it via the below approach-

```
@FeignClient(name="email-service", url ="${email.url}")
public interface EmailService 
{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value="/send_mail", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)                                                                                   
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","x-auth-id: {email.xauthid}"})
    void sendData(@RequestBody Map<String, ?> formParams);
}



In application.properties of define the configuration
email.url=<<url-for-sending-mail>>
email.xauthid=110
```